# no module named crypto.cipher

Tags: python, python-2.7, encryption

I'm trying my hands on encryption for a while now. I recently got hands on this python based crypter named [PythonCrypter](https://github.com/jbertman/PythonCrypter).

I'm fairly new to Python and when I try to open the CodeSection.py file via terminal, I get error saying `from Crypto.Cipher import AES
ImportError: No Module Named Crypto.Cipher`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: you need to install pycrypto

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't seem like a well-managed project - there's no `requirements.txt` or `setup.py` to let you easily install it and its dependencies. You will need to identify any third-party packages it depends on yourself, and install them manually. Searching for `Crypto.Cipher` leads you to [`pycrypto`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pycrypto), for example.

Comment: Was a solution ever found for this issue? I'm having the same problem on Ubuntu 17

Answer (score 50):

```
pip uninstall Crypto
pip uninstall pycrypto
pip install pycrypto
```

That works for me.

The point is, when you install `pycrypto`, you should remove `Crypto` first

Comment: This works. I also had to do a reboot before installing pycrypto again. Can be necessary sometimes.

Answer (score 15):

I just encountered this issue with Python 2.7 on Windows.  My solution was to rename the folder from ..\site-packages\**c**rypto to ..\site-packages\**C**rypto.  The lower case "c" was causing the import error.

See https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/3309 for details.

Comment: This was the same problem I had.  Thank you very much.

Comment: Just encountered the same on my Mac.

Answer (score 8):

In order to use the pycypto library you should install it with:

```
pip install pycrypto
```

or

```
easy_install pycrypto
```

Comment: @KanishkSingh try to download the tar file and install it. https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pycrypto

Comment: @Arion_Miles It's seems to be a problem with vcvarsall.bat, you need to install visual studio c++, for more info click the link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2817869/error-unable-to-find-vcvarsall-bat

Comment: Yes, I installed the C++ compiler mentioned and pycrypto install all perfectly, but this program still has trouble importing crypto.cipher
I believe it's because my Pycrypto is stored within 'C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages' and this program might be trying to fetch it from 'C:\Python27\Scripts'

Comment: have you tried to copy the files  there? @Arion_Miles

Answer (score 3):

PyCrypto doesn't play well with Windows systems if you're installing using pip or easy_install... or at least it didn't for me.

Try using the prebuilt binaries for Windows here:
http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/modules.shtml#pycrypto

Comment: Tried what you suggested. Installed "PyCrypto 2.6 for Python 2.7 32bit" It installed correctly but I'm still getting the same error.

Comment: @Arion_Miles Is it possible that you have two separate versions of Python installed on your machine has two versions of Python installed? Also, looking at the comments above, if Pycrypto is in 'C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages' (which is where it should be), you should make sure that is included in your PATH variable within Environment Variables.

Comment: Do I need to specifically add "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages" in my environment variables path? If not, then what do I need to add?

Comment: @Arion_Miles Usually when you install Python, it adds it the the environment variables path for you, but if it's not there, then yes, specifically add "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages"

Comment: Btw, for more information on how Python interacts with the system path as defined in environment variables, check out this [link](http://www.diveintopython3.net/your-first-python-program.html#importsearchpath)

Answer (score 2):

I just spent half an hour figuring this out on Ubuntu. Turns out, I had installed the `python-pycryptopp` package through apt (I prefer to avoid pip if possible), but the package I needed was actually `python-crypto`.

Answer (score 2):

In ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS installing pycryptodome package resolved the issue

Comment: `pycryptodome` package is needed if you are using Python3.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, pycrypto package was not installed, when I tried to add it: I ran into the following error which was rectified by downloading and installing [C++ Compiler for Python 2.7](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=44266).

error: Microsoft Visual C++ 9.0 is required. Get it from http://aka.ms/vcpython27

Answer (score 0):

I think u should try this:

```
sudo pip2 install pycrypto
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this has already been answered, but I want to expand a little bit

```
pip install Crypto --> IS THE WRONG PACKAGE
```

if you do this run the below to remove it:

```
$> pip uninstall Crypto
```

Now, to install type:

```
$> pip uninstall pycrypto --> just in case you have a broken package already

$> pip install pycrypto
```

On **macOS Catalina** this will automatically install the **pycrypto** package for **Python3.6** ONLY.

This means that if you run:

```
python your_script.py
```

It wil fail. Unless of course **Python3** is set as your default.

Now if you really want to run **pycrypto** on **Python2** you can run the below

```
$> sudo pip2 install pycrypto
```

You will need the sudo for this to work!

This will install **pycrypto** for **Python2** only.

I hope this helps someone who might be installing then running with python2, or who wants the package installed with **Python2** but is continuously installing with the **Python3** package