# Getting this error: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named ‘crypto.PublicKey’ even after installing crypto

Tags: python, pip, pycharm

I downloaded PyCharm today and installed Crypto, but it says that it's missing, I tried almost all the solutions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19623267/importerror-no-module-named-crypto-cipher).

I'm using a Mac and I should be using pip3 to install any package.

Also, take a look at this screenshot, the screenshot shows the result when I search for crypto. Maybe this could be the problem:

[image: Screenshot]

Here is my code:

```
from firebase import firebase

firebase = firebase.FirebaseApplication("https://smallworld-89f21.firebaseio.com/")
data = {
    "Name" : "Abdullah",
    "Age" : 20
}

result = firebase.post("smallworld-89f21/hellYeah", data)
print(result)
```

This is the error I'm getting:

[image: Error]

Comment: 1) What is the actual import code you're using? 2) What is that a screenshot _of_? Please [edit] your question to include a little more detail

Comment: Oh okay, Ill edit the question

Comment: @G.Anderson I have edited the question, hope it's clear now :)

Comment: Try `from Crypto.PublicKey import RSA`. Python imports are case-sensitive, and the docs suggest it's capitalized.

Comment: @MihaiChelaru now the error is “No module named Crypto”

Comment: Ensure that you've installed the library in the same interpreter you're using in PyCharm. How is your Python interpreter configured? It's possible you've installed it into a different Python installation. You've not showed how you installed the package and how you set up PyCharm.

Comment: I downloaded the crypto from PyCharm itself, I’m sure that it has not been installed into a different python version

Answer (score 0):

try

```
from crypto import PublicKey
#use PublicKey.RSA
```

Comment: cannot import name 'PublicKey' from 'crypto' (/Users/ajmal/PycharmProjects/Main/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/crypto/__init__.py)

Comment: the module Crypto is there but PublicKey isn’t there, is there any way to download PublicKey?

Comment: I installed it,and it seems like, it's a app, go to crypto's file, you may see ```app.py```, try to run it

Comment: It seems like it will use with a command prompt which inputs what it need for work, but it's working weird tho.

Comment: There was an error in app.py, it was a spelling mistake, it should Crypto not crypto, but it still hasn’t fixed the error, it’s just that the PublicKey is missing

Comment: you need to change the file name into Crypto.

Comment: look into [it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31485110/no-module-named-crypto-cipher/31485157), maybe this will help you.

Comment: and also you may try install ```pycrypto```

Comment: I commented out the from Crypto... line and now it works, is it okay if I just leave it at that? Or...?

Comment: Tried installing pycrypto too, no luck

Comment: I don't think that will last long... You could change file name to match the package

Answer (score 0):

Let me try to help you. The correct package to install is pycrypto. And I think you didn't install it through pip that is why it is giving error.

```
pip install pycrypto
```

Comment: Hey, some of the answers in some other question said the same thing, but it didn’t work for me

Comment: How did you install crypto?

Comment: I first installed from the terminal but I got the same error, and the. I downloaded PyCharm and installed it from there and I still got the same error

Comment: if you are using python3 try pip3 install pycrypto

Comment: Tried that too, I’m still getting that error, it’s just that the PublicKey is missing, anyway I could download that?